# Continuous extension of factorial (and other) summations

Tags: real-analysis, functions, summation, factorial, gamma-function

Suppose we have the following function of the natural numbers $k \in {\mathbb N}$:

$$f(k) = \sum_{r=0}^k \sum_{h=0}^{r}  (h+r)!$$

We would like to extend $f$ to all of ${\mathbb R}^+$.
We know that $(h+r)! \approx \Gamma(h+r+1)$,
but what is the right way to "continuize" the discrete summations?

Is there a general strategy?

In other words, suppose we have function $q:{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N} \rightarrow \mathbb N$ and an extension $q^*:{\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^+} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ i.e. $q^* |_{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N} \equiv q$.  Now given a function 
$$p(k) = \sum_{r=0}^k \sum_{h=0}^{r}  q(h,r)$$
How could one extend $p$ to a smooth differentiable function $p^*$ that is defined on all of ${\mathbb R}^+$? Let's assume that $q^*$ is continuous, infinitely differentiable and any other properties needed.

Comment: It depends what characteristic of the original function you want to preserve. By example: the Euler gamma function preserves the relation $(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$ for all it values, and set $\Gamma(1):=1$

Answer (score 2):

My first step would be
to reduce the
number of summations.

$\begin{array}\\
f(k) 
&= \sum_{r=0}^k \sum_{h=0}^{r}  (h+r)!\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^k \sum_{h=r}^{2r}  h!\\
&= \sum_{h=0}^{2k} \sum_{r=\lceil h/2 \rceil}^h  h!\\
&= \sum_{h=0}^{2k} (h-\lceil h/2 \rceil+1)h!\\
&= \sum_{h=0}^{2k} (\lfloor h/2 \rfloor+1)h!\\
\end{array}
$

At this point,
you might be able to use
the fact that
$\sum_{h=0}^k h h!
=\sum_{h=0}^k (h+1-1) h!
=\sum_{h=0}^k ((h+1)!-h!)
=(k+1)!-1
$.

Another possibility
is to see how
$f(k)$ grows.

$\begin{array}\\
f(k+1)
&=\sum_{r=0}^{k+1} \sum_{h=0}^{r}  (h+r)!\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{k} \sum_{h=0}^{r}  (h+r)!+\sum_{h=0}^{k+1}  (h+k+1)!\\
&=f(k)+\sum_{h=0}^{k+1}  (h+k+1)!\\
&=f(k)+\sum_{h=k+1}^{2k+2}  h!\\
\end{array}
$

At either of these points,
I don't see how to go further.

Note:
I was unsure about the
reversal of summations,
so here is how I checked:

r=0 -> 0!

k=0 -> 1

r=1 -> 1!, 2!

k=1 -> 1

r=2 -> 2!, 3!, 4!

k=2 -> 2

r=3 -> 3!, 4!, 5!, 6!

k=3 -> 2